# How to find the WebSphere7 server start/stop history in server

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

How can I find history of websphere 7 server start or stop from command line or any other logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startServer.log, stopServer.log files contain this information.  Additionally, the startup can be seen in the SystemOut.log file as well.  Finally, if Verbose GC logging is enabled, the native_stderr.log file will have entries for each JVM restart as well.

These can all be found in {WebSphere Install Dir}/profiles/{Profile Name}/logs/{server name}.